# Jenkins login error using python jenkins (Cloudbees Jenkins)

Tags: python, jenkins, cloudbees

```
import jenkins

jen = jenkins.Jenkins(url="https://us1****xhpu******************.com:9080/" ,username="sk******", password="00326aef7*******************15695")

print jen.get_whoami()
```

**Note:** Password is API token

Error:

> requests.exceptions.SSLError:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='**********************', port=9080): Max
>   retries exceeded with url: /crumbIssuer/api/json (Caused by
>   SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate
>   verify failed (_ssl.c:590)'),))

I tried https → http but not working.

Comment: try with 
    jenkins = Jenkins(url, username, password, ssl_verify=False)

Comment: Okay, It tried -> TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ssl_verify'

Answer (score 5):

This below code worked

```
import jenkins
import os
os.environ.setdefault("PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY", "0")
jen = jenkins.Jenkins(url="https://<hostname>:9080/" ,username="user", password="<password/API token>")
print jen.get_whoami()
```